# How to count table rows for each value in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new here so if its not fixed topic please fix me.
I have this table:

```
id | uid | month | year
-----------------------
1 | 5 | 12 | 2018
2 | 5 | 12 | 2018
3 | 9 | 12 | 2018
4 | 3 | 01 | 2019
```

I want to count how much times for each `uid` the `month` and `year` values equal to - `month=12` AND `year=2018`

for example I want to get response like that:

```
uid=5 - count = 2
uid=9 - count = 1
```

How its possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the sql query to select and group by type and count per type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635241/how-to-write-the-sql-query-to-select-and-group-by-type-and-count-per-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `group by uid`:

```
select uid, count(*) as counter
from table
where month = 12 and year = 2018
group by uid
```

Comment: Hi, first thank for answer. I try to order the results by the count, here is what I add to query: `ORDER BY count(*) DESC` whats wrong?

Comment: Oh I am sorry my fault - its work fine without order by. Thanks for your best answer!

Comment: The order by is fine, what is the problem?

Comment: see my last comment

Comment: Fine, I was typing when you posted.

Comment: Add to query: ORDER BY counter DESC would work, if not already in the order anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select uid,
       sum(case when year = 2018 and month = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from t
group by uid;
```

This will include `uid`s with a count of 0.  If you just want uids where the count is greater than 0, use a `where` clause:

```
select uid, count(*)
from t
where year = 2018 and month = 12
group by uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select uid, count(*) from table where year=2018 and month=12 group by uid